# How to customise Material-UI sticky header for horizontal scroll?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Material UI tale with the sticky header on CodeSandox: https://codesandbox.io/s/yi98d?file=/demo.tsx

I added a stickyHeader prop on a Material UI table, but when I scroll horizontally the left side header cells slide one behind another. (See photo [with stickyHeader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8v7I.png))

When I remove a stickyHeader prop, header cells get a fixed position and on horizontal scroll move together with a table content cells, but obviously, it doesn't stick to the top on a vertical scroll. (See photo [without stickyHeader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Sza.png))

So the question is how to make the header to stick on a vertical scroll, but on horizontal scroll move it as normal without any effects? Sorry if my question is silly, I am new to programming and please explain it step by step. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are props for stickyheader:

```
.MuiTableCell-stickyHeader {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    position: sticky;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

Just remove left: 0; and it should work